# What Wordpress file is saving new users to database

Tags: database, users, username

I need to know, what Wordpress php file is saving new users to database. I can't find it, but I need to modify new users usernames before it's added to DB.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[user.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1.1/src/wp-includes/user.php#L1698)

To modify usernames before a user is added, use the filter `pre_user_login`.  Hope that helps.